# How can I make my ASCII art generator more effecient?

Tags: python, image, optimization, python-imaging-library, ascii

I have made a black-and-white ASCII art generator in Python. However, it feels a bit slow at times. For larger images, generating an image can take more than 30 seconds. I have noticed that I am using two lazy generator streams, one for `unscaled_chars` and one at the bottom of `make_ascii`. I want to join them to have only one generator here, but I do not know how as it has gotten very complex trying to do so. Does anyone who is familiar with optimizing code have a few tips as to how I can make `make_ascii` take less time?

```py
from PIL import Image
from os import get_terminal_size

def make_ascii(filename):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    pixels, img_width, img_height = img.getdata(), *img.size
    term_height = get_terminal_size()[1]

    numerator, denominator = (term_height, img_height) \
        if term_height > img_height else (img_height, term_height)
    scale = numerator // denominator

    def unscaled_chars():
        for i, pixel in enumerate(pixels):
            if (i + 1) % img_width == 0:
                yield "\n"
            else:
                avg = sum(pixel) // 18
                yield f"_{chr(avg)}" if avg >= 32 else "██"

    for y in range(1, len(usc := "".join(unscaled_chars()).split("\n")), scale):
        for x in range(0, len(usc[0]), scale):
            yield usc[y - 1][x]
        yield "\n"

for pixel in make_ascii("../../link_sprite.png"):
    print(pixel, end = "")
```

Comment: Since you've posted working code and are just looking for tips to improve it, you might not get much of a response since that's more of a job for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (which, if you post on there, you should make sure to read the rules so that post doesn't get closed). StackOverflow is more for getting help troubleshooting code issues. I'd also recommend doing more research beforehand, such as profiling your script to figure out which parts take the most amount of time, so people here don't have to do all that legwork themselves.

Comment: @RandomDavis when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_".

Comment: @RandomDavis Good tip. I'll do that.

Comment: Adding sample input and corresponding output images might help explain what you are trying to do.